# My Amd switchable Graphic Card is not recognized

Tags: ati

My graphics card is not being recognized. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and have the switchable AMD ATI  6620G and 6600M.  I have downloaded the proprietary driver (AMD Catalyst 12.10 and 12.11) both are not installing giving me a error message saying "one or more of the reqired tools not found. Optionally you can force using --force. This is not recommended it can make your 3d acceleration unstable" and recently my computer does not start all it does is give me a message saying "running in low graphics settings" and I cannot proceed using the enter key so I'm forced to manually restart.

I'm horribly frustrated and am coming from using Windows my entire life and minimal use of command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The following link is easy to follow and should fix your problems :)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

I also have the same computer, the issue is that hybrid graphics are not very well supported at the moment. So you chose a hard computer to come over to ubuntu.